# Git tab missing in RStudio after git installed on Windows

Tags: r, git, svn, version-control, rstudio

Installed R, R Studio, Git but when I opened R Studio, there was no Git tab,

like the screenshot below:
[image]
Windows 8.1, x64
R version: 3.5.1
R Studio version: 1.1.463
Git: 2.19.2

When I opened Tools/Global Options/GitSVN:
Git executable: `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe`
SVN executable: `C:/Program Files/Git/bin/sh.exe`
* I cannot find any file called "svn.exe" in the git folder.

I tried to solve the issue by following methods, but none of them work:
1. After I ran `Sys.which("git")`in the R Studio, the output was:
`"C:\\PROGRA~1\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe"`, so I tried to change the git executable to `cmd/git` instead of `bin/git`, not work.
2. Re-install everything, no success.
3. Tried older Git version 2.14 but still no success.

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a great question to post over at the RStudio Community site where they actually provide community support for RStudio

Comment: don't know if it applies, but  note that the "git" button is only available if you are inside a RStudio project corresponding to a folder "associated" to a valid git repository.

Comment: Thank you, I cloned a project from git and not I can see the tab

Comment: You have to create a "version control" project in RStudio. If you already did it, restart RStudio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to see the Git tab in the upper right pane in RStudio, one must create an RStudio project, as follows.

Starting from the RStudio main panel, there is no `git` tab prior to loading a project

[image]

Select **File > New Project** from the main menu bar to create a project

[image]

Select **New Directory** on the dialog box that appears.

[image]

Next, fill out the new project information, check the create git repository box, and press the **Create Project** button.

[image]

Once the project has been created, the **Git** tab is now visible in the upper right quadrant of RStudio.

[image]

See also [Version Control with Git and SVN](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN) on the RStudio support website.

Comment: Got it, I just cloned a project, I can see the git tab now, thank you so much

Comment: That's right, if you clone a project from a remote repository and then use existing directory when configuring the project in RStudio, it adds the git tab. I'm glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 2):

Also had this problem (Git tab disappearing in a project that was already cloned and had been working perfectly well before, and I was still able to push/pull from the Git GUI)

What solved the issue for me was View->Panes->Zoom Git, which made it appear again

Then you just need to adjust the pane layout to what you had before

Comment: This just worked for me too, on RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin" for Windows

Answer (score 1):

An additional answer, as I got the following problem:

After correctly installing RStudio and cloning a Git R project, I had indeed the Git tab. However, after a while, the Git tab didn't show when opening the project. The project was still a Git project, as could be checked from a Git bash terminal.

Solution: the path to git.exe was mysteriously lost in RStudio options. Put it back, restart RStudio, and everything is all right.

I might be useful to know where this option is stored: on Windows, it's in a JSON dictionary, namely `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\RStudio\rstudio-prefs.json`, under the key `git_exe_path`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Deleting the `git_exe_path` key solved this for me!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to a desired Git Project > Fork
2. On R Studieos > Create New project > Version Control > Git > Give details
3. New git project created. Icon will be seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are continuing existing git project from local, you can open the repository-name.Rproj file and the Git tab will show up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).